# How to handle radio event when iCheck-helper is used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to handle the radio button on change event. But, as the designer has already used iCheck-helper, the actual radio actions are not performed when the code is run.

Below is the code

```
<div class="radio-wrap">
   <input type="radio" id="bg-effect" value="full" />Full Image
</div>
```

When we run the code and inspect the code in chrome, the generated HTML is as below.

```
<div class="radio-wrap">
  <div class="iradio_minimal-grey checked"><input type="radio" id="bg-effect" value="full" checked="" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></ins></div>Full Image
</div>
```

To capture the selected value, I want to handle the change event for this radio button.

Comment: Have you tried the solution? Did it work? If not, could you add some comments?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/#callbacks), you can use `ifChanged` event like this:

```
$('#bg-effect').on('ifChanged', function(event){
    alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But, I'm struggling to get the selected radio value. Please suggest.

Comment: $('input[name="bg-effect"]').on('ifClicked', function(event){
   alert("You clicked " + this.value);

Comment: With the above code I achieved what I wanted. Thanks :)

Comment: Worked for me, the key was trying to figure out which html tag and which attribute to choose in the selector - should have been obvious and debugging in browser was confusing as the <input> did not see to be the one receiving the checked attribute.  This answer solved it for me.  +1 for putting a link to the docs in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I ran throught the same problem,later i found useful fix as has been correctly answered from github forum :  [read from this thread](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck/issues/68)

The following was a fix:

```
$('input').on('ifCreated ifClicked ifChanged ifChecked ifUnchecked ifDisabled ifEnabled ifDestroyed check ', function(event){                
                    if(event.type ==="ifChecked"){
                        $(this).trigger('click');  
                        $('input').iCheck('update');
                    }
                    if(event.type ==="ifUnchecked"){
                        $(this).trigger('click');  
                        $('input').iCheck('update');
                    }       
                    if(event.type ==="ifDisabled"){
                        console.log($(this).attr('id')+'dis');  
                        $('input').iCheck('update');
                    }                                
                }).iCheck({
                    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-green',
                    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-green'
                        //increaseArea: '20%'
                });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this fix really helped out