# Radio not working as expected on JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, radio-button

I'm trying to manage an onChange event from a radio button. It's supposed to be as simple as :

```
$('#Form').change(function(){
  $('#Form').submit();
});
```

But the code is not working.

I'm using JQuery and the HTML generator is JSP (which I guess that is the problem).

I have tried also, getting by input, by class... by all! And even getting the change in ALL the form (which is the code shown above)

Any help or tip in this JSP radio button problem will be really appreciated.

Thank you guys!

P.S: I tried the same code on pure HTML and it is working, the problem is just with JSP

EDIT: Inputs in JSP are like:

```
<input type="radio" name="tipo"  value="value" ${checked}> Value
```

Which result in html like:

```
<input type="radio" name="tipo"  value="value" > Value
```

Comment: Please provide your html code

Comment: This was the problem, the iCheck... This answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562062/how-to-handle-radio-event-when-icheck-helper-is-used

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
   $('#Form').submit();
});
```